# Multiple meta_queries Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

have done a bit of searching round these parts for an answer and yet to find a satisfactory explanation for why my code doesn't work... basically I'm trying to perform a meta_query with 3 arrays and one relational operator. If someone could let me know where I'm going wrong it would be a massive help, bare in mind I have tested this code using only 2 arrays and it works for all the given keys when there are two arrays, just not three:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'posts_per_page' => '6',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'article_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'mood_boards_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'real_weddings_featured_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
            ),
    );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, cheers!